# How would one go about implementing `zipWithIndex` in underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Essentially when zipWithIndex is applied on an array it should produce another array with key as value and value as the array element (or vice versa).

Comment: Is the question how to implement the `zipWithIndex` method from Scala in JavaScript? `_.map(myArray, function(e, idx) { return [e, idx]; });` deals with the array version, but what are you envisioning for objects exactly?

Comment: @tavnab: I think I accepted your answer too quickly looking at the code. But that's not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: zipWithIndex(["a", "b", "c"]) => [["a":0], ["b":1], ["c":2]]. Yours is very close to what I want, but I see that the inner arrays have size as "2": [ [0: "a", 1: 0], [0: "b", 1: 1], [0, "c", 1: 2] ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81043/discussion-between-tavnab-and-venkat-sudheer-reddy-aedama).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Based on the OP's comments, the return value should be an array of objects, each of which contains a single property which is an inverted property (i.e. keys & values swap places) of the input array/object.

```
function invert(list) {
  return _.map(list, function(val, key) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[val] = key;
    return obj;
  });
}
```

Example 1: `['a', 'b', 'c'] ==> [{a:0}, {b:1}, {c:2}]`

Example 2: `{key1:'a', key2:'b'} ==> [{a:'key1'}, {b:'key2'}]`

```js
function invert(list) {
  return _.map(list, function(val, key) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[val] = key;
    return obj;
  });
}


function doAlert(input) {
  alert (JSON.stringify(input) + ' ==> ' + JSON.stringify(invert(input)));
}

doAlert(['a', 'b', 'c']);
doAlert({key1: 'a', key2: 'b'});
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Like the [`_.invert`](http://underscorejs.org/#invert) function in Underscore.JS, the values must be serializable (i.e. convertable to strings) for this to have predictable behavior.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Consider:

```
function zipWithIndex(list) {
  return _.map(list, function(val, key) { return [val, key]; });
}
```

This actually should work with both objects & arrays (anything that can be iterated, as far as `_.map` is concerned).

This implementation of `zipWithIndex` is based on [Scala's implementation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) (the only widely used language I could find with this function defined).

```js
function zipWithIndex(list) {
  return _.map(list, function(val, key) { return [val, key]; });
}
  
function doAlert(input) {
  alert (JSON.stringify(input) + ' ==> ' + JSON.stringify(zipWithIndex(input)));
}

doAlert(['a', 'b', 'c']);
doAlert({key1: 'a', key2: 'b'});
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```